# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float) - Loan Status Classification

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, floating-point

I'm trying to preprocess a loan dataset with mixed-data types

My training data:

```
index,Loan_ID,Gender,Married,Dependents,Education,Self_Employed,ApplicantIncome,CoapplicantIncome,LoanAmount,Loan_Amount_Term,Credit_History,Property_Area,Loan_Status
0,LP001002,Male,No,0,Graduate,No,5849,0.0,NaN,360.0,1.0,Urban,Y
1,LP001003,Male,Yes,1,Graduate,No,4583,1508.0,128.0,360.0,1.0,Rural,N
2,LP001005,Male,Yes,0,Graduate,Yes,3000,0.0,66.0,360.0,1.0,Urban,Y
3,LP001006,Male,Yes,0,Not Graduate,No,2583,2358.0,120.0,360.0,1.0,Urban,Y
4,LP001008,Male,No,0,Graduate,No,6000,0.0,141.0,360.0,1.0,Urban,Y
```

I used a for loop for assigning data-types to each name:

```
for name, column in loan_features.items():
  dtype = column.dtype
  if dtype == object:
    dtype = tf.string
  else:
    dtype = tf.float32

  inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)
```

My model:

```
def loan_model(preprocessing_head, inputs):
  body = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  preprocessed_inputs = preprocessing_head(inputs)
  result = body(preprocessed_inputs)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)

  model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
  return model

loan_model = loan_model(loan_preprocessing, inputs)

#fit
loan_model.fit(x=loan_features_dict, y=loan_labels, epochs=10)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f067c1d54a2b> in <module>()
     77 
     78 #fit
---> 79 loan_model.fit(x=loan_features_dict, y=loan_labels, epochs=10)
     80 
     81 #save

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    103 
    104 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Most of the code is following a CSV tutorial I found in Tensorflow.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Also, it looks like your code formatting isn't quite right; please double-check.

Comment: I provided some training data I used. Also, can you specify what code formatting issues I have? I'm a beginner so everything may not be obvious to me, unfortunately.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. If you look at your second Python code snippet, it looks like there's an extra single quote at the front of it (notice how the first snippet has proper syntax highlighting, but the second is completely green).